# Finding a source package for libsn

Tags: gcc

I am trying to compile the i3 window manager from source, which requires a header file from libsn (#include ).

I cannot find libsn's source package from anywhere and would like help locating it.

Answer (score 0):

Fourth result from typing "libsn" into Google gives [this](https://github.com/strake/libsn). It's not a "package", but in order to find a package, we'd have to know what kind of package you need - RPM, DEB, tar.gz, ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate a current version of the package: startup-notification-devel

I was trying to build i3 on CentOS 7, which includes startup-notification but not startup-notification-devel. My compilation was successful by using the package from RepoForge for CentOS 6. Exact commands will depend on your distribution, but here are the general steps.

**Install RPMforge**: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

*Quick reference for CentOS 6/7 x86_64:*

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.*.rpm
```

**Install the package**:

```
yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras startup-notification-devel
```

If you're not using RHEL/CentOS then you may want to download the source:
http://www.freedesktop.org/software/startup-notification/releases

Instructions to compile the libraries are available at the Linux From Scratch project:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/startup-notification.html